# select parent node if all children have assigned class

Tags: jquery

I am looking for an efficient way to traverse a unordered list which contains multiple levels which contain the class .selected.  If all the UL LI in a group have the class .selected, I need to add the class .selected the parent LI of the child UL.

```
<ul>
    <li>one <-- this li adds class .selected if ALL its children have .selected
        <ul>
            <li class="selected">red</li>
            <li class="selected">green</li>
            <li class="selected">blue</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>two
        <ul>
            <li class="selected">red</li>
            <li>green</li>
            <li class="selected">blue</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

if ALL the children in any given UL have the class .selected add the class .selected to the parent LI, so in this case the LI containing the text "one" would be the only parent LI to have the class .selected added.

I need this to happen when the page loads. and I have tried a bunch of methods but this one came closest but I am not too sure if its the most efficient:

```
$("ul li").filter(function () {
    var lis_total = $(this).siblings().length + 1;
    var lis_selected = $(".selected", this).siblings().length + 1;
    if(lis_total == lis_selected)
        return $(this).parent("li").addClass("selected");
});
```

I am not too sure if I am doing it correctly. Its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want a one-liner, try http://jsfiddle.net/4JNaL/

```
$('li ul:not(:has(li:not(.selected)))').parent().addClass('selected');
```

or

```
var theParent = $('li ul:not(:has(li:not(.selected)))').parent();
```

to return the element for manipulation

for trees of arbitrary depth: http://jsfiddle.net/GQbmU/4/

```
do {
    $results = $('li:not(.selected) > ul:not(:has(li:not(.selected)))');
    $results.parent().addClass('selected');
} while ( $results.length > 0);
```

or, since the theme of this answer is one-liners: http://jsfiddle.net/GQbmU/6/

```
while ( $('li:not(.selected) > ul:not(:has(li:not(.selected)))').parent().addClass('selected').length > 0) {} ;
```

Comment: I like this solution, now how can I keep traversing the tree until I hit the root.  In my case the unordered list could be huge and I would like to select the first li in the parent node until I hit the root.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
$("ul li").filter(function () {
    var all = $(this).find('> ul > li'); //get all immediate ul and its immediate li's
    var selected = $(this).find('> ul > li.selected'); //get all immediate ul and its immediate li's with class selected

   return all.length && all.length == selected.length; //return if there are li's and all are selected
}).addClass('selected'); //add class
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hapsx/)**

Comment: The only issue I have is that this does not traverse the tree enough, how would I keep going until I hit the root?

Comment: If the ordered list was say 10 levels deep, I only wanted to add the .select class to the first li in each parent ul li until I hit the root. I tried PrevAll() but that selects everything before the .select class.

Comment: You want to look up only in the first li of each ? I am sorry i probably still did not get it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $("ul").filter(function () {
        var lis_total = $(this).children("li").length + 1;
        var lis_selected = $(this).children("li.selected").length + 1;
        if (lis_total == lis_selected) {
            $(this).parent("li").addClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ugh.. only 11 minutes too late. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/ecixez/2/edit

```
$('li>ul:has(.selected)').each(function(){
  if($('.selected', this).length === $('li',this).length) // if 3 == 3 :)
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```