# Defining a jQuery function in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I think I have written a function that should be working/loading but it is not. I am working on a site that is built on WordPress and so I don't know if the way I am defining the function is not working with word press or if there are other issues.

My JavaScript in an external file is

```
jQuery.fn.tapFilter = function(action) {
    if (action === "hide") {
        jQuery(this).addClass('tap-hidden');
        jQuery('.ptb_list-post:not(:has(article:not(.tap-hidden)))').parent('.tap-subcategory').addClass('tap-hidden');
        return this;
    }
    if (action === "show") {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('tap-hidden');
        jQuery('.ptb_list-post:has(article:not(.tap-hidden))').parent('.tap-subcategory').removeClass('tap-hidden');
        return this;
    }
};
```

I think this is valid. I'm more of a designer that is dabbling in programming. I know the jQuery has to be used instead of the $ in WordPress.

I am trying to check if the function exists by calling this on the page

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  if (typeof tapFilter == 'function') {
    alert("Function Exists" );
  }
});
```

The page in question is http://truthaboutporn.org/all-research.

Comment: What type of action are you trying to bind to  the tapFilter function (ex. click, hover,, etc.)? Also do you have a HTML snippet?

Comment: Interesting website. Out of general intrigue, who is funding this project?

Comment: (Addendum - propaganda websites frequently don't have information about who is funding them, as is the case here. I was thinking maybe the Scientologists - they do the same with their anti-drugs stance - or at least a religious organisation of some kind).

Comment: Ah, just stumbled on this nonsense again, and I was right - [it is being promoted by a cult](https://www.thedailybeast.com/porn-kills-love-mormons-anti-smut-crusade). Not the Scientologists, but close!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure why it wasn't loading at first but in rewriting the way the function was declared i got it to load and run on the page.

```
function(a) {
  a.fn.tapFilter = function(x) {
    if (x === "hide") {
      jQuery(this).addClass('tap-hidden');
      jQuery('.ptb_list-post:not(:has(article:not(.tap-hidden)))').parents('.tap-subcategory').addClass('tap-hidden');
      return this;
    }
    if (x === "show") {
      jQuery(this).removeClass('tap-hidden');
      jQuery('.ptb_list-post:has(article:not(.tap-hidden))').parents('.tap-subcategory').removeClass('tap-hidden');
      return this;
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

The other biggest issue i had was understanding the difference between `.parent()` and `.parents()`. I had to go further up the DOM tree, I realize I didn't post a html snippet here which would have been helpful with the question.

The script to hide the the parent element was based on this question: 
[select parent node if all children have assigned class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579426/select-parent-node-if-all-children-have-assigned-class)